# Dynamically including a Rails Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My objective is to dynamically load a set of methods to an ActiveRecord model instance based on an attribute that's set:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize do |cp|
    self.class.include "#{cp.subject}".constantize
  end
end
```

I then have the following concerns:

```
module Ruby
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def get_framework
        'rails'
    end
end

module Python
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def get_framework
        'django'
    end
end
```

Then, when I run these separately, I get the correct framework string:

```
python_book = Book.create(:subject => 'python', :id => 1)
python_book.get_framework -> 'django'

ruby_book = Book.create(:subject => 'ruby', :id => 2)
ruby_book.get_framework -> 'rails'
```

My problem is that when I have both of the books returned in a query, the Concern is included is the last in the result set and is not picking up the correct Concern methods.

```
Books.all.order(:id => 'asc').collect do |book|
    puts book.get_framework
end

# Result
['rails', 'rails']
```

I am assuming that this is because the 'include' is happening at the class level and not the instance level. Would love some help as to how to clean this up and make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-extend)
to add instance methods to a instances of `Book` instead.

Extends in action:

```
module Greeter
  def say_hello
    "Hello"
  end
end
```

---

```
irb(main):008:0> a = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x00000101e01c38>
irb(main):009:0> a.extend(Greeter)
=> #<Object:0x00000101e01c38>
irb(main):010:0> a.say_hello
=> "Hello"
irb(main):011:0> Object.new.say_hello
NoMethodError: undefined method `say_hello' for #<Object:0x00000101e196d0>
```

---

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize do |cp|
    self.extend subject.constantize
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I just smacked myself in the forehead. That worked and thanks for the explanation.